# Modified D'Alembert's Principle Inquiry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

So I had been handed a differential equation to describe a "fluid's" motion ("fluid" because we are actually talking about plasma) inside the sun. I quickly digress to mention the frustrations of trying to type a mathematical equation into this this thing. [The differential equation is as follows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HKHi.png) It is very similar to the D'Alembert's Principle, but with the addition of the second derivative with respect to position it has thrown off my approach a couple of times. I was wondering if there exist a Modified D'Alembert's Principle where it takes into account that b != 0.

Comment: Are $\gamma$ and $g$ constants, or is either one a function of $x$ (and $t$)?

Comment: gamma here is the constant representative of the adiabatic exponent and g is gravity of the sun to which we assume constant over the region we are we studying (chromosphere to corona)